# MultiProcessing Pool not executing function

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pool

I have been dealing with this for the past 5hrs and I don't know what I am doing wrong. It just prints "Running pool..." but it doesn't seem to be executing the function. It doesn't throw any errors it just keeps running.

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host, user=user,port=port,passwd=password, db=dbname)

SQL = 'SELECT * FROM Clean_SBIR LIMIT {}, 20000'

def process_data(offset):
    print('Offset original: ',offset)
    offset = offset * 20000
    print('Actual offset: ',offset)
    df = pd.read_sql((SQL).format(offset), conn)
    print(offset)
    return len(df)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool(4) as pool:
        print('Running pool...')

        result = pool.apply_async(process_data, [1,2,3])
        print(result.get())
        print(pool.map(process_data, [1,2,3]))
```

Comment: Did it print `'Offset original: '...` ?

Comment: No, it only printed "Running pool..."

Comment: You might want to try `Threading` instead of `multiprocessing` so that you don't mess with your `conn` instance.

Comment: How would it mess with my conn instance?

Comment: `multiprocessing` will run the script again, once for each process it creates, thus possibly creating more instances of `conn`.

Comment: Would it work if I use a local csv file and chunk it and then use pooling to run each chunk?

Comment: That sounds more appropriate use of `multiprocessing` where you are cpu-bound. Although it will copy the chunks around, so difficult to say if you will gain a performance boost.

Comment: Try moving the `conn` definition into the `process_data` function.